# プロトコルについて

Tags: swift

プロトコルへの適合チェック（is,as）は、@objcで修飾したプロトコルものに限定されるみたいなのですが、@objcで修飾されていないプロトコルを適合したクラス、構造体は、プログラマが実装時に責任を持つことになるのですか？

@objcで修飾されていないプロトコルはどうのように考えるべきなのですか。
なにかピンときません。

教えてください

Answer (score 5, accepted):

それは昔のSwiftの制限ではないでしょうか。初期のSwiftはランタイムの制限により実行時にプロトコルの適合を判断できませんでしたが、現在は`@objc`の付いてないプロトコルに対しても、`is`、`as`でプロトコルに適合しているかどうかをチェックすることができます。

より詳しくは下記のドキュメントの「Checking for Protocol Conformance」のところをご覧ください。

> Checking for Protocol Conformance
>   You can use the is and as operators described in Type Casting to check for protocol conformance, and to cast to a specific protocol. Checking for and casting to a protocol follows exactly the same syntax as checking for and casting to a type:
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: 詳解Swiftで勉強しているのですが、古いのでしょうか。

Comment: 詳解SwiftはSwift 1.1の時の書籍なので2.0とかかなり変わってしまってますね。

Comment: バージョン変更に伴う、機能の変更、追加がわかるような資料があれば教えてください

Comment: アップルのSwiftブログ https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=29 や Swiftのサイト https://developer.apple.com/swift/ などが良いと思います。 https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift2 こちらや https://medium.com/swift-programming/lets-try-swift-version-swift-2-9a90cd738d53#.kj4g32cbk もわかりやすくまとまっています。あとはSwift 2で検索したらいくらでも見つかりますよ。

Comment: swiftを勉強し始めたばかりなので、どのようなバージョン遍歴がおこなわれたかもわかっておらず、今回のプロトコルチェックは、swift2.0からの変更なのでしょうか？つまり、swiftの言語仕様を勉強するには、詳解swiftとswift2から機能の変更・追加内容を確認したらよいのでしょうか。英語は読めません。

Comment: このプロトコルの話はランタイムの変更によるものなので特殊ケースですが、一般的にはアップルのリリースノートやドキュメントの更新履歴などから当たるのが確実です。日本語の情報はWebを検索すれば出てきます。そろそろ書籍なども増えてきているのでそれをご覧になるのも良いと思います。